# How to enforce multi-level limits on resources?

Tags: limit

I'm working on an application where resources need to be allocated and the allocated resources are grouped in multiple hierarchical groups.
There are limits on the number of allocated resources on every level of the hierarchy but the limit on a level is always lower the the sum of the limits of the children of that level.

The following example might make things more clear:

```
              +----+
              | A1 |
              +----+  
         _______|_______
        |               |
     +----+           +----+
     | B1 |           | B2 |
     +----+           +----+
    ___|___           ___|___
   |       |         |       |
+----+   +----+   +----+   +----+
| C1 |   | C2 |   | C3 |   | C4 |
+----+   +----+   +----+   +----+
```

With this hierarchy, a resource that is allocated in group `C1` obviously counts towards the limit of group `C1`, but also towards the limit of groups `B1` and `A1`.
Now let's define the following limits:

- Maximum number of allocated resources in any `C` group : 2
- Maximum number of allocated resources in any `B` group : 3
- Maximum number of allocated resources in any `A` group : 4

Here are a few examples of resource allocations that are valid:

- Each `C` group has 1 allocated resource: this is within the limits of a `C` group, for `B1` and `B2` (2 allocated resources each) and for `A1` (4 allocated resources).
- `C1` has 2 allocated resources and `C2` has 1 allocated resource: this gives both `B1` and `A1` each 3 allocated resources, which is within the limits.

Here are a few examples of resources allocations that are not valid:

- `C1` has 4 allocated resources: this violates the limit for `Cx` groups.
- `C1` and `C2` each have 2 allocated resources: this violates the limit for group `B1`.
- `C1` and `C3` have 2 allocated resources each, while `C2` and `C4` have 1 allocated resource each: this doesn't violate the limits of the `B` and `C` groups, but brings the total for `A1` to 6 allocated resources, which is invalid.

I'm now trying to implement a resource management component that enforces all these limits.
As resources are allocated on the `C` level, I've come up with an architecture where there are `limiter` objects for each level and each `limiter` has access to its parent in the higher level:

```
class Limiter {
    int max;
    int current;
    Limiter *parent;

    bool check_increment(int n) {
        if (current + n > max)
            return false;
        else if (parent)
            return parent->check_increment(n);
        else
            return true;
    }

    void allocate(int n) {
        current += n;
        if (parent) parent->allocate(n);
    }
}

A1_limiter = Limiter(max = 4, parent = null);
B1_limiter = Limiter(max = 3, parent = A1_limiter);
B2_limiter = Limiter(max = 3, parent = A1_limiter);
C1_limiter = Limiter(max = 2, parent = B1_limiter);
C2_limiter = Limiter(max = 2, parent = B1_limiter);
C3_limiter = Limiter(max = 2, parent = B2_limiter);
C4_limiter = Limiter(max = 2, parent = B2_limiter);
```

This allows me to set up the hierarchy up front and perform limit checks later on without having to take the exact hierarchy into consideration.
When I want to allocate a resource, I would do the following:

```
if (C1_limiter.check_increment(1))
    C1_limiter.allocate(1);
else
    // handle resource limit reached error
```

This all works pretty well as long as I'm only trying to allocate resources in one specific `C` group at a time.
But sometimes I need to allocate resources in multiple `C` groups in one go.
For example: try to allocate 1 resource in group `C1` and `C2` each, but allocate none if that would violate any limits.
I could, of course, check and allocate the resources on group by group basis and roll back if a limit is reached:

```
for (limiter : limiter_list) {
    if (limiter.check_increment(1))
        limiter.allocate(1);
    else
        // rollback
        return;
}
```

The problem with this approach is that resource allocations are expensive and the rollback is complex, so I want to avoid that.
Ideally I want to be able to perform all the checks first and know that all allocations are allowed, before actually starting on the allocations.
The following won't work, however, because the upper layer groups (`A` and `B`) can't know the total amount of resources that will be allocated in their groups:

```
for (limiter : limiter_list) {
    if (!limiter.check_increment(1))
        // no rollback necessary because nothing was actually allocated
        return;
}
for (limiter : limiter_list) {
    limiter.allocate(1); // limits may be exceeded because A and B groups never check their total
}
```

So my question is: how can I implement the allocation of resources in multiple groups in one go without the need for rollbacks?
Is that possible using my current Limiter class or should I use a different architecture/algorithm alltogether?

Comment: Can't you just work this out with functions that *simulate* allocations without actually performing them so that a rollback has no cost ?